# Read .csproj VersionPrefix property in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, .net-core-2.0

I'm setting up CI/CD in TeamCity for some Core 2.0 projects, and I want to read the VersionPrefix from the .csproj file. I do **not** want to set the VersionPrefix from TeamCity (I've read those answers).

We maintain 2 branches - develop and master. Check-ins against the develop branch are built and packed in TeamCity with a VersionSuffix of "rc%build_counter%". Part of our process is to identify whether the update is a Major, Minor or Patch release and set the VersionPrefix manually during planning.

This way our nuget server has pre-release versions for others to test with, along with a latest stable version, i.e.:

- MyPackage1.0.0
- MyPackage1.1.0-rc1
- MyPackage1.1.0-rc2
- MyPackage1.1.0

I'm using the TeamCity "OctopusDeploy: Create release" build step, which takes a Release number property, so I need a way to read the VersionPrefix in TeamCity and set it as the new release number.

BTW, if there's any way to omit this in TeamCity and just pick the version up on the Octopus side, I'm all ears.